# Creating relational Tables in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, datatable, relational-database

I have to change my first question to the following:

I have 3 tables:

Clients, 
Gender, 
Race

Clients:

```
ClientID long integer
GenderID long integer
Gender   short text
RaceID   long integer
Race     short text
```

Gender:

```
GenderID long integer
Gender   short text
```

Race:

```
RaceID  long integer
Race    short text
```

What should I do in order to be able to modify data in the main table Clients -so they'd be changed according to content in Race / Gender tables

For example:

Gender table:

```
GenderID  Description
       1  Male
       2  Female
```

Clients table:

```
ClientID GenderID  Gender  DOB
      11       2   Female  1/1/1977
      12       2   Female  1/2/1970
      13       1   Male    1/4/1969
```

So, if I'd modify for example, ClientID "13" Gender to "Female" instead of the current one "Male", so that the GenderID would be automatically changed to "2"?
(And no other number would be allowed for that GenderID)

Or - if I'd modify ClientID from 1 to 2, I want the Gender to be changed to "Female"

Thank you, again

Comment: You don't have a natural key in the client table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use both a character-field, `Race`, *and* a foreign-key field, `RaceID`, in your schema design: you should only use the latter, `RaceID`.

You shouldn't, *and-d-d-d,* you don't need to.

Your reports and so forth would then be based upon a query which `JOINs` to all three tables – displaying the `Race.Race` value `("White")` but never the *(meaningless ...)* `RaceID` integer.

Your input-fields would be combo-boxes which query *(say)* the `Race` table to find possible values, binding on the `RaceID` field.

The `Clients` table contains foreign-key numbers which the end-user never actually sees.  Queries *(and combo-box parameters)* are used to reference the corresponding strings.

You should also use Referential Integrity constraints to ensure that `Clients.RaceID`, if it is not `NULL`, must be a value in the `Race` table.

Comment: It's not clear to me...   Do you mean, in my main Clients table i should only use RaceID, ClientID  but not Race and Client fields?  And, when I'll join all 3 tables - I'll use the Race , Client from the Race and Client tables?

Comment: Also, if I'll build the query combining all 3 tables, and then - will create the form based on that query (creating a Form is my main goal) then - I won't be able to modify that form. But I need to be able to enter data and to modify my resulting form

Comment: You base your form on your Client table. You add list boxes to your form to select gender and race. I suggest reading up on MS Access a bit before you start, this is all basics you should understand before starting.

Comment: What question is this answer answering?

Comment: @Mike Robinson  Thank you! Your explanation (with some MsAccess relational databases video) helped. It works perfectly after I changed relations & more carefully designed my tables